# Is my vm using GPU, committed GPU and Preemptible GPU?

Tags: google-cloud-platform

When I create a 'Deep Learning VM' instance and I choose a GPU, then I would think that I'm choosing the regular GPU, rather than preemptive or committed. But based on the quota for each and the estimated hourly cost, I think they're assigning me committed GPU's. So,

1. How do I find out what kind of GPU's are being assigned to my machine?
2. How do I choose the one I want?

Answer (score 1):

> How do I find out what kind of GPU's are being assigned to my machine?

The following GPUs are available to use:

```
For compute workloads, GPU models are available in the following stages:

NVIDIA® Tesla® T4: nvidia-tesla-t4: Generally Available
NVIDIA® Tesla® V100: nvidia-tesla-v100: Generally Available
NVIDIA® Tesla® P100: nvidia-tesla-p100: Generally Available
NVIDIA® Tesla® P4: nvidia-tesla-p4: Generally Available
NVIDIA® Tesla® K80: nvidia-tesla-k80: Generally Available

For graphics workloads, GPU models are available in the following stages:

NVIDIA® Tesla® T4 Virtual Workstations: nvidia-tesla-t4-vws: Generally Available
NVIDIA® Tesla® P100 Virtual Workstations: nvidia-tesla-p100-vws: Generally Available
NVIDIA® Tesla® P4 Virtual Workstations: nvidia-tesla-p4-vws: Generally Available
```

> How do I choose the one I want?

Depending on which way you use the Google Cloud you can do it by using the Console or the gcloud CLI.

If you want to change it after checking the list of available zones with the GPUs, you can go to the **Machine Configuration** section and select the type of the machine you want to use.

In the **Machine Configuration** section, by clickong on the CPU platform and GPU you can see the advanced machine type options and available GPUs.

Clicking on the **GPUs** tab will show yo uthe list of available GPUs.

Basically, you should check the list of the available machines in your zone and see which one fits your needs.